# PHP multi array file

Tags: php, arrays, url-rewriting

Hi Guys I am new to this, I have an array predefined in a php file, I can load the specific array from the file and then display it and then user update the value and submit. After that I want that new value to be updated in the file as well.
source.php

```
   $System_load = array(
    'SOURCE1' => array(
       'hostname' => 'Server1',
    'colour' => 'Red',
       ),
    'SOURCE2' => array(
    'hostname' => 'Server1',
    'colour' => 'Blue',
        ),
   )
```

update.php

```
   $hostname = $_REQUEST['hostname'];
   $eNumber = $_REQUEST['eNumber'];
   function load($file, $eNumber) {
       include $file . '.php';
       return $config[$eNumber];
   }
   $array =(load('source',$eNumber));
   $replacement = array('hostname' => $hostname);
   $update = array_replace($array, $replacement);
   // this shows me the array with new updated value
   print_r($update);
   echo "update sucessful";
```

I want the new value to be updated in source.php

any pointers will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: See [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php) or [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php). That being said, I'd recommend storing the data in a different format, say `ini` or `json`

Comment: [`Maybe worth a read`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578894/can-one-php-file-edit-another)

Comment: I tried that already, what happens that it delete other arrays from the .php file and write only current array.

Comment: @user3822629 you aren't `"putting"` back into the file which is why it doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the data in a more usable format than PHP source code. For example, `source.json`

```
{
    "SOURCE1": {
        "hostname": "Server1",
        "colour": "Red"
    },
    "SOURCE2": {
        "hostname": "Server1",
        "colour": "Blue"
    }
}
```

and in your PHP

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('source.json'), true);

// do stuff to the $json array

file_put_contents('source.json', json_encode($json));
```

Comment: Thanks phil for your answer, We have to stick with source code array. its requirement for the project.

Comment: It's ridiculous. You should question that

Comment: This array belongs to a application which use these values to create auth token for ibm IDP .. I did try to convert the array with Jason but it didnt recognised it well.

Comment: @user3822629 um `json_decode($json, true);` makes it an array. Just apply it to the correct variable...?

Comment: I just try Json but it stop the application to operate.