# Load variables from external file in PHP

Tags: php, variables, import, external, config

How can I import a variable from an external file? What I want to do is to have a configuration file in which I can write all my website settings and then to import these settings to every file, so I can set the website skin and things like that.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237291/php-reading-file

Comment: There's also [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at this :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

you'll be happy :)

Answer (score 12):

You can have a file with configuration and then include it on every script, like jeroen told you:

config.inc.php

```
$config['dbname'] = 'myDB';
$config['dbuser'] = 'user';
```

...

then in your scripts

```
include_once('config.inc.php');
```

You could also use inheritance where you have a model for example that uses the config and then you can extend that model class.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to store your configuration. You can just include a php file that has stuff like:

```
$config['stuff'] = "value";
```

but you can also use a config (ini) file or a xml file. PHP has standard functions available to read config files or xml files, so that´s easy as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `auto_prepend_file` to prepend your settings in every PHP scripts that is executing. It's inside the `php.ini`, or you can use `.htaccess` (`php_value auto_prepend_file "path/mysettings.php"`), or using `ini_set()`. The file must be a valid or existing.