# Save PHP variables to a text file

Tags: php, file

I was wondering how to save PHP variables to a txt file and then
retrieve them again.

Example:

There is an input box, after submitted the stuff that was written in
the input box will be saved to a text file. Later on the results need
to be brought back as a variable. So lets say the variable is $text I
need that to be saved to a text file and be able to retrieve it back
again.

Comment: actually you cannot save a variable but only it's value.

Comment: Actually, you can save variables, but not in a clean way. It's always possible to `compact()` your variables in an array and later `extract()` them, though.

Comment: @Duroth you are absolutely right.If you can please give me more idea.Thank you

Comment: *(sidenote)* If you only want to persist the form data between requests, consider using Sessions.

Comment: All the answers are answering your specific question, but Gordon is absolutely right: It really sounds like you want Sessions.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This should do what you want, but without more context I can't tell for sure.

Writing `$text` to a file:

```
$text = "Anything";
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('filename.php', $var);
```

Retrieving it again:

```
include 'filename.php';
echo $text;
```

Comment: thank you very much.You are a genius.Actually this is what I am looking for...!!Working perfectly.Thanks again dear friend

Comment: Bad way, because problem with security. You can included some code with vulnerability.

Comment: @mishanon Who has access to this file except you?

Comment: Note that returning value is possible too: `<?php return $var_str`. Then you can use a different name for included data e.g. `$someText = (include 'filename.php');`

Answer (score 52):

Personally, I'd use file_put_contents and file_get_contents (these are wrappers for fopen, fputs, etc).

Also, if you are going to write any structured data, such as arrays, I suggest you serialize and unserialize the files contents.

```
$file = '/tmp/file';
$content = serialize($my_variable);
file_put_contents($file, $content);
$content = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: alternate approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237291/php-reading-file/2237315#2237315

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry I can't comment just yet, otherwise I would)

To add to Christian's answer you might consider using `json_encode` and `json_decode` instead of `serialize` and `unserialize` to keep you safe. See a warning from the PHP man page:

> **Warning**
>
> Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize(). Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

So your final solution might have the following:

```
$file = '/tmp/file';
$content = json_encode($my_variable);
file_put_contents($file, $content);
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

**for_example**, you have anyFile.php, and  there is written `$any_variable='hi Frank';`

to change that variable to `hi Jack`, use like the following code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('anyFile.php'); 

$new_content = preg_replace('/\$any_variable=\"(.*?)\";/', '$any_variable="hi Jack";', $content);

file_put_contents('anyFile.php', $new_content);
?>
```

Comment: this is what i need after saving, i need updating. Thanks @T.Todua

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of of `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fread`. PHP.net has excellent documentation and **examples** of each of them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: Thank you for your caring.Unfortunately, I think you don't get me.

Comment: There is no problem with the references.Which is very helpful.Thank you once again.But, this is not actually what I am looking for.

Comment: You asked for a way to write contents to a find (fwrite) and a way to read it back into a variable (fread) I personally agree that Christian's answer is better, but this does the same thing.

Comment: Ajith, if my answer solved your question, then this one would have also as 'file_put_contents' is simply a wrapper function for the functions in Kerry's answer. Perhaps we both misunderstood though?

Comment: You have to put more effort in describing what you want then if none of the suggestions here help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize()` on the variable, then save the string to a file. later you will be able to read the serialed var from the file and rebuilt the original var (wether it was a string or an array or an object)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I needed a solution to this, and I borrowed heavily from the answers to this question and made a library: <s>https://github.com/rahuldottech/varDx</s> (Licensed under the MIT license).

It uses `serialize()` and `unserialize()` and writes data to a file. It can read and write multiple objects/variables/whatever to and from the same file.

Usage:

```
<?php
require 'varDx.php';
$dx = new \varDx\cDX; //create an object
$dx->def('file.dat'); //define data file
$val1 = "this is a string";
$dx->write('data1', $val1); //writes key to file
echo $dx->read('data1'); //returns key value from file
```

See the github page for more information. It has functions to read, write, check, modify and delete data.