# How to create a text file to save form data in?

Tags: php, html, forms, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save PHP variables to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995461/save-php-variables-to-a-text-file)

I need help to take data entered into an html form and create a new file with the name of the file being what the user enters in for there name and then save that text file into a folder called forms or something.

Comment: file name and file content are other text box or same .

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];  //posted value of text box
$userName =$_POST['userName'];   //posted value of text box
$myFile = $fileName.".txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $userName;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```