# How to use file input/output to add, delete and display data uploaded by the user in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file, upload

I'm having trouble with my project for my beginning PHP class here's criteria:
 using PHP, allow any number of products to be added to your online store via a web page (not manually editing the code or a file). At minimum, for each new product you should add  its name, description, image, and price.

After each product is added display the revised product list to a table.  The product list should be saved to a file, so that the updated inventory shows up the next time you access the online store.

So I already made my form that a user can fill out, the confusing part for me is after the user clicks submit.  I just can't figure out how to incorporate the "file" into my code so that it fits my project criteria (allowing users to "add" information without tweaking with the code or file).  Again, thank you in advance, and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Here is my index.php (form)

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="display.php" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <h1>Product Information Page</h1>
    <p>Product Name: <input type="text" name="product_name" /></p>
    <p>Product Description: <input type="text" name="product_description" /></p>
    <p>Price: <input type="text" name="price" /></p>
    <p>Upload Product Image: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
        </form>


        <?php

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my display.php

```
<?php

$productFile = "file.txt";
if(!empty($_POST['product_name']))
//the following variables are grabbing specific information from the form.
$product_name = array($_POST['product_name']); 
$product_descriptoin = array($_POST['product_description']);
$price = array($_POST['price']);
$image = array($_POST['file']);


    echo '<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10">'; 
    echo "<tr align='center'>
            <td><b>Product Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Product Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Price</b></td>
            <td><b>Image</b></td>
          </tr>"; 
foreach ($product_name as $key=>$display) 
    {                
        echo "<tr align='center'>";
            echo '<td>';
            echo $product_name[$key];
            echo '</td>';            
            echo '<td>';
            echo $product_descriptoin[$key];
            echo '</td>';           
            echo '<td>';
            printf('$%', $price); 
            echo $price[$key];
            echo '</td>';          
            echo '<td>';
            echo "<img src='".$image[$key]."' width='200' height='300' align='center'>";
            echo '</td>';
     } 
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
     echo '</table>';


$ourFileName = "file.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [store data into a text file using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365570/store-data-into-a-text-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I got, lets see if it works for you.

This is on page "index.php"

```
<?php
/* Author: Rick Kazman
 * Created: 11/1/2008
 * Modified: 10/28/2013 to allow data file to be stored in current folder
 * Description: This program displays a table of products and allows products to be added to
 * the online store. The new product contains a product number, description, image, and price.
 */
include "functions.inc"; 

// Useful variables
$datafile = "products.dat";
if (!isset($errors)) $errors = array();

/********************************************
 * Populate and update the array of products.
 ********************************************/
if (array_key_exists("add_item", $_POST))
{
    // If the user has added an item, validate it.  If valid, add it to the array
    $products = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
    $new_item = $_POST['new_item'];
    $errors = validate_price($errors, $new_item['price']);
    $errors = validate_product($errors, $new_item['prodNum'], $products);
    if (count($errors) == 0)                   // Only add the item if there are no errors
    {
        $products[] = $new_item;
        unset($_POST['new_item']);
    }
    array_to_arrayfile($products, $datafile);  // Rewrite the data file
}
else if (array_key_exists("delete_item", $_POST))
{
    // If the user has added an item, add it to the array and save the file
    $products = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
    $selected = $_POST['to_del'];
    $size = count($products);

    // Find all the products selected for deletion and remove them
    for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        if (isset($selected[$i]) && $selected[$i] == "on")  unset($products[$i]);
    }

    $products = array_values($products);       // Reorder the array
    array_to_arrayfile($products, $datafile);  // Rewrite the array file
}
else
{
    if (!file_exists($datafile))  // Data file doesn't exist, so create it
    {
/*      $product1 = array('prodNum' => 'P1221',
                      'description' => 'Double Bubble Windscreen',
                      'image' => 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT9B6kGG3G1q1Ag1bqPI0ERrNgCaO8aeQxOhvtuStpNDBs-8smK',
                      'price' => 50);
        $product2 = array('prodNum' => 'P1346',
                      'description' => 'Michelin Pilot Power 2ct Set',
                      'image' => 'http://www.motorcycletoystore.com/sport/images/uploads/power2t.jpg',
                      'price' => 300);
        $product3 = array('prodNum' => 'P2094',
                      'description' => 'Scotts Steering Damper',
                      'image' => 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwTD43wbFLr9vCP36C1ANaq-6bSI3XoU9N8IIUdkbGVw1pz7_UBA',
                      'price' => 350);
        $product4 = array('prodNum' => 'P3942',
                      'description' => 'Frame Slider',
                      'image' => 'http://fstg.motosport.com/motographics/images/products/Metric/07body/LP_CarbonInlaySlider.jpg',
                      'price' => 100);
        $product5 = array('prodNum' => 'P8055',
                      'description' => 'Yoshimura Exhaust',
                      'image' => 'http://www.motorcycle-superstore.com/ProductImages/300/0000_Yoshimura_TRC_Slip-On_Exhaust.jpg',
                      'price' => 850);
        $products = array($product1, $product2, $product3, $product4, $product5); */
                $products = array();
        array_to_arrayfile($products, $datafile);
    }
    else
    {
        $products = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
    }
}
/***************************
 * Display the product array
 ***************************/
?>

<form method='POST' action='<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>'>
<h1>Welcome to the MotoStuffe Shoppe!</h1>

<table border =3>
<tr><td><b>Delete?</b></td>
<td><b><center>Product#</center></b></td>
<td><b><center>Product</center></b></td>
<td><b><center>Description</center></b></td>
<td><b><center>Price</center></b></td><tr>

<?php
foreach ($products as $key => $product)
{
    // Print each table row: Product#, Product image, Description, Price
    $prodNum = $product['prodNum'];
    $image = $product['image'];
    $price = sprintf("$%.2f", $product['price']);
    $desc = $product['description'];
    echo "<tr><td><center><input type=Checkbox name=to_del[$key]></center></td><td><center>$prodNum</center></td>" .
         "<td><center><img height=150 src=$image></center></td><td><center>$desc</center></td><td><center>$price</center></td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<!-- Get user input / report errors / make forms "sticky" -->

<table>
<tr><td>Product#:</td><td><input type='text' name='new_item[prodNum]'
    value= "<?php  if(isset($_POST['new_item'])) {$tmp = $_POST['new_item']; echo $tmp['prodNum']; } ?>" >
    <?php if (isset($errors['product'])) echo " <font color='red'>{$errors['product']}</font>"; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Image:</td><td><input type='text'  name='new_item[image]'
    value= "<?php  if(isset($_POST['new_item'])) {$tmp = $_POST['new_item']; echo $tmp['image']; } ?>"  ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Description:</td><td><input type='text' name='new_item[description]'
    value= "<?php  if(isset($_POST['new_item'])) {$tmp = $_POST['new_item']; echo $tmp['description']; } ?>"  ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Price:</td><td><input type='text' name='new_item[price]'
    value= "<?php  if(isset($_POST['new_item'])) {$tmp = $_POST['new_item']; echo $tmp['price']; } ?>"  >
    <?php if (isset($errors['price'])) echo " <font color='red'>{$errors['price']}</font>"; ?></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Delete Item(s)" name="delete_item"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Add Item" name="add_item"></td></tr>
</table></form>
<?php $errors = array(); // Clear the errors array  
?>
```

This is on the second page called "functions.inc"

```
<?php

// Useful functions
// Created by: Rick Kazman
// Creation date: October 31, 2013

function array_to_arrayfile($theArray, $filepath)
{
    // This function serializes an array in $theArray and saves it
    // in the file at $filepath. The file may then be converted
    // back into an array using the arrayfile_to_array() function)
    if ($fp = fopen($filepath, "w+"))
    {
        $encoded = serialize($theArray);
        fwrite($fp, $encoded);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else
        echo "Unable to write array to $filepath";
}

function arrayfile_to_array($filepath)
{
    // This function reads the file at $filepath and returns an
    // array. It is assumed that the file being read is a
    // serialized array (created using array_to_arrayfile)†
    $fsize = @filesize($filepath);
    if ($fsize > 0)
    {
        $fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
        $encoded = fread($fp, $fsize);
        fclose($fp);
        return unserialize($encoded);
    }
    else
        echo "$filepath does not exist!";
}


function validate_price($errors, $value)
{
    if( !is_numeric($value) || $value - round($value, 2) != 0 || $value <= 0 )
    {
         $errors['price'] = "Invalid price -- please re-enter";
    }
    return $errors;
}

function validate_product($errors, $prodID, $products)
{
    foreach ($products as $key => $aProduct)
    {
        if ($prodID == $aProduct['prodNum'])  // If the product ID already exists, reject it
        {
            $errors['product'] = "Invalid product ID -- please re-enter";
            break;
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

?>
```