# File not being created even though write permissions exist

Tags: php, file, permissions, file-permissions

I followed the selected answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995461/save-php-variables-to-a-text-file#comment3059037_2995461), I am trying to export what is in the memory for a certain variable to a .php file. Then I later require_once the php file that was made.

The problem is that the php file is never being made. So when I try to require it, I get an error (HTTP 500 as the code depends on this one variable and because this file does not exist).

The error log says the file can not be required because there is no such file or directory.

The dir that I am trying to make the file in has 755 permissions.

Here is the code that I am using to export the variable to a file:

```
$variable_export = var_export($elasticaObject, true);
$variable = "<?php\n\n\$$elasticaObject = $variable_export;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('theIndex.php', $variable);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and why the file theIndex.php is not being made?

Comment: What's the return value from `file_put_contents`?

Comment: does `theIndex.php` already exist? The dir might be 755, but if theIndex.php already exists and is owned by some other user, then you still won't be able to overwrite it.

Comment: @andrewsi How do I get the return value from file_put_contents?

Comment: @MarcB No, it does not already exist.

Comment: @IMUXIxD `$myval = file_put_contents('theIndex.php', $variable); var_dump($myval);` That will tell you the number of bytes written, or false if it fails.

Comment: If the directory has 755 permissions, it means only the directory owner can create files there. Is it owned by the same userid that the webserver runs in?

Comment: @Barmar no, the server, itself, doesn't belong to me. I am just a user on the server.

Comment: @andrewsi Nothing is being printed.

Comment: You need to put the file in a directory that's writable by the server userid, not you.

Comment: @Barmar how can I figure out with dir is writable by the server userid?

Comment: Find out from the hosting provider.

Comment: @Barmar he is trying, but everything he tries is not working. for some reason it is not working. the file isn't being written.

Answer (score 0):

Your mode may be insufficiant.

755 = RWX (Owner), RW (Group and Others).

Group and Others may just read and cross the folder.

That could be an issue if the user that launch PHP is not the owner of the folder.

Try a chown user:group on the folder, so your php-user (probably your webserver) could write in it.

Cheers,

K.

Comment: how do I do a chown user:group. Can you update your answer explaining how.

Comment: Suppose your directory is "/home/koreth/test" : `chown www-data:www-data /home/koreth/test`. www-data is the default user for Apache on Debian, should be something else for an other distribution.

Comment: I'm not using apache, i'm using lightpd. But I am using debian.

Comment: So I guess you should replace www-data:www-data by lighttpd:lighttpd in my comment.