# Simplest XML Node Editor for PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

Could someone please provide the simplest/shortest code that can edit the values within an xml node? I have been searching this for hours and all that I get are errors and failures. I need something that can get the node (/node/node1/node2) and edit the contents within it. I am using php-5. Thanks

*Edit:* Lets say I have this xml file:

```
<node>
  <node2>
    Content
  </node2>
</node>
```

What I need to do is change the value of `<node2>` from `"content"` to something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/example.xml');

// Note the SimpleXMLElement is the root node, ie <node>
$doc->node2 = 'new content';

$doc->asXml('new-filename.xml'); // Note, saves locally
// or
$xmlString = $doc->asXml();
```

Comment: What would I need to add if the xml is a remote file?

Comment: @Phil Brown It is adding new nodes, not updating the current ones. Is there any other code you can provide? thanks

Comment: @Preston I don't think you can add new nodes using that method. Always thought you had to use `SimpleXMLElement::addChild()`. In any case, it would probably be very specific to the document structure. Perhaps you could add an example to your question.

Comment: @Preston Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @Phil Brown For some reason, it is still adding another <node2></node2> tag at the end of the file and keeping the other part also. Any other suggestions/code?

Comment: @Preston Are there any other `<node2>` nodes? If so, you need to identify which one to modify by its index, eg `$doc->node2[0] = 'new content';`

Comment: @Phil Brown Thank you for the help. I finally got it by doing this: $doc->node->node2[0] = 'new content';

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), great class for XML parsing/editing