# How could i parse this xml string with Simple Xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<form>
    <field name=”name”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”lastname”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”country”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”usstate”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”email”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”password”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”type”>VALUE</field> 
    <field name=”iscustomer”>1|0</field> 
    <field name=”newsletter”>1|0</field> 
    <field name=”privacy”>1|0</field> 
    <field name="udid">VALUE</field> 
    <field name="hash">VALUE</field>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know how since i am not a php programmer.

Comment: [PHP manual: SimpleXML: Basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why negative votes? This is a legitimate question, isn't it!? I've seen stupider.

You want: [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string)

```
$xmlString = ' your xml ';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
// jimy's code here
```

Comment: I've seen stupider too, but is our mission really to save people from taking a 1-minute look into the manual?

Comment: Good point =) Agreed. I revoke my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path_to_file');
foreach($xml->children() as $child){ 
     print_r($child);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

Comment: @user663942: Did you check that the path to the file was valid?

Answer (score 0):

The XML you posted isn't actually readable - you're using a mix of double quote styles in the example you copied. If you fix that, this code will convert what you want into an associative array:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$values = array();
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{ 
    $values[(string)$child->attributes()] = (string) $child[0];
}
print_r ($values);
?>
```