# reading data from xml in php

Tags: php, xml

Have a problem that i really need some help on. I have been given an XML file to use which I need to convert into PHP to use on my site. I have very limited experience with XML and normally they are in a simple format, but this particular XML file has values on each element:

http://partnerfeed.itsfogo.com/partnerfeed.aspx?partnerfeedID=1726&ZoneID=128470&partnerTargetLink=&partnerField=itsfogoTargetLink

I need to pull through specific data dependant on a value within the XML file. Due to my lack of knowledge with this I wonder if someone could help explain the process to do this so i understand better. I really need to know how to get the xml file and then load specific elements of it. I have looked at simplexml but havent really understood it.

As an example I need to show the data where league = "Premier League" and then show all the child values within that specific league.

Any help here would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: Google offers almost 5 million results for "parse xml php".

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up a function called `simplexml_load_string()` - this will take a text string - or in your case the XML.
You can get the XML String using `file_get_contents()`. With `simplexml_load_string()`, you get returned an object which portrays the whole structure of the XML file, you can then traverse this till your heart is content, quick, simple and easy!

You might want to double check that your actual XML syntax is valid & structured in a way which makes it easy to traverse when you parse it to an Object with `simplexml_load_string()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = file_get_contents("http://partnerfeed.itsfogo.com/partnerfeed.aspx?partnerfeedID=1726&ZoneID=128470&partnerTargetLink=&partnerField=itsfogoTargetLink");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
var_dump($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called [`simplexml_load_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) while bypasses the requirement to use `file_get_contents` first.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://partnerfeed.itsfogo.com/partnerfeed.aspx?partnerfeedID=1726&ZoneID=128470&partnerTargetLink=&partnerField=itsfogoTargetLink');
```

The function return a [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object which you can use to go through that DOM.