# Search XML file *based* on search criteria and remove nodes - ASP or PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

I am not looking for an exact attribute or and exact node text. Example

```
<Items>
  <book>
    <title> Beginning Java </title>
  </book>
   <book>
    <title> Beginning ASP </title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title> Beginning Java </title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title> Advance Java </title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title> Advance ASP </title>
  </book>
</items>
```

What I want to be able too is find all books that has "Beginning" in the title or "Advance" in the title. Sort of wild type search. What do I need, XPATH? Either ASP.NET or PHP code will help.

I am doing this to write a utility to remove broken links in iTunes music library on MAC.

Thank you

**Edit: Help needed with the actual XML**
I am searching based on the  in front of "Location" key. Never came across such an XML which has  and .

Thanks again

```
<key>5175</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>5175</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>02 - Track 02</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Abba</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>Abba Gold</string>
        <key>Genre</key><string>English</string>
        <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Size</key><integer>5816448</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key><integer>242285</integer>
        <key>Track Number</key><integer>2</integer>
        <key>Date Modified</key><date>2003-09-28T14:37:38Z</date>
        <key>Date Added</key><date>2011-06-19T20:30:08Z</date>
        <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>192</integer>
        <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
        <key>Persistent ID</key><string>9030665BDB2B4A20</string>
        <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
        <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/macbookpro/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Abba/Abba%20Gold/02%2002%20-%20Track%2002.mp3</string>
        <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of XPath (1.0) which ASP.NET and PHP support with the normal installations you can use `/Items/book[contains(title, 'Beginning') or contains(title, 'Advance')]`. Note that XML node names and therefore XPath expressions are case-sensitive, your sample is not well-formed XML as it has a start tag `<Items>` but an end tag `</items>`.

As for code to remove nodes with ASP.NET, try along the following lines:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.xml");
XmlNodeList booksToRemove = doc.SelectNodes("/Items/book[contains(title, 'Beginning') or contains(title, 'Advance')]");
for (int i = booksToRemove.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  booksToRemove[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(booksToRemove[i]);
}
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: your answer is bang on target but I need more help with my actual post. I have posted the code in the original question. Also my compiler VS2010 (.NET 4) was complaining about booksToRemove.Length. I had to use .Count instead. Thank you

Comment: I actually used a different code as I have updated the code above. The line booksToRemove[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(booksToRemove[i]); still does not work for me. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
//book[contains(title, 'Beginning') or contains(title, 'Advance')]
```

This should do it