# php preg_match pattern for parsing tags

Tags: php, xml, design-patterns

I want to know a good preg_match pattern in php for extracting data between tags.

For example :

```
 <page>
    <username>someone</username>
    <id>3020778</id>
    <text xml:space="preserve"> The quick brown fox. </text>
 </page>
```

This will give me the string "The quick brown fox".

I have tried using

```
preg_match('/<text(.*)?>(.*)?<\/text>/', $content, $match);
```

But it seems doesn't work on some other cases.

Does anyone have a better solution or pattern?

And does using simpleXML make it more faster than preg_match?

Comment: There are some things that regular expressions are very good at. IMNSHO, parsing XML isn't one of them. Use an XML parser and get your data that way :)

Comment: Typically speaking, parsing your XML documents is almost always more reliable than using regular expressions.

Comment: This one sums it up nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `$page = simplexml_load_string($xml); echo $page->username, $page->id, $page->text;` Also see [A simple program to CRUD Node values of an XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file), [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044) and [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $a = '<page>
<username>someone</username>
  <id>3020778</id>
  <text xml:space="preserve"> The quick brown fox. </text>
</page>';

preg_match_all("(\<.+\>(.+)\<\/.+\>)U",$a, $r);    
?><pre><? print_r($r);?></pre><?
```