# PHP parse single result in XML file

Tags: php, syntax, simplexml

I am having a syntax issue. The following code prints all of the names from an XML file.

```
$url = 'http://my-xml-file';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->PERSON as $PERSON) {
  echo '<div>' . $PERSON->NAME . '</div>';
}
```

The XML file has now changed and only has 1 person with 1 name in it. How can I modify the code above to echo a single name?

Thanks

UPDATE I have simplified it a bit but the basic XML structure looks like this:

```
<PERSON>
<NAME>Tom</NAME>
</PERSON>
```

Comment: What does the XML you are parsing actually look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($xml->NAME as $name) {
  echo '<div>' . $name . '</div>';
}
```

or just

```
echo '<div>' . $xml->NAME . '</div>';
```

if there is only 1 entry !

Example : http://codepad.org/g6WUggDq

This is using the XML you supplied .... There should be an outer element surrounding your XML like `<document>` and a valid header `<?xml version='1.0'?>`