# how to parse this xml data using php?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="infosys.com/" HOME="0" AID="=">

   <RLS PREFIX="http://" more="62">
   <RL HREF="wipro.com/" TITLE="Wipro Corporation"/>
   <RL HREF="tcs.com/" TITLE="Tata Consultancy Services"/>
   <RL HREF="satyam.com/" TITLE="Satyam Computer Services Ltd"/>
   <RL HREF="ibm.com/" TITLE="IBM Corporation"/>
   <RL HREF="rediff.com/" TITLE="Rediff.com India Ltd."/>
   <RL HREF="moneycontrol.com/" TITLE="MoneyControl.com"/>
   <RL HREF="in.com/" TITLE="IN.com"/>
   <RL HREF="google.co.in/" TITLE="Google India"/>
   <RL HREF="www.stiknowledge.com/" TITLE="Business Process Outsourcing | Help Desk    Outsourcing And Certification"/>
   <RL HREF="www.sourcinginterests.org/" TITLE="Sourcing Interests Group"/>
   <RL HREF="www.dice.com/" TITLE="www.dice.com/"/>
   </RLS>
   <SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="DMOZ" HOST="infosys.com">
   <TITLE TEXT="Infosys"/>
   <ADDR STREET=" 44, Electronics City,  Hosur Road" CITY=" Bangalore,  KARNATAKA  560 100" STATE="" ZIP="" COUNTRY=" India" />
   <CREATED DATE="17-Jul-1992" DAY="17" MONTH="07" YEAR="1992"/>
   <PHONE NUMBER="91 80 852 0261"/>
   <OWNER NAME="Infosys Technologies Limited"/>
   <EMAIL ADDR="marketing@infosys.com"/>
   <LANG LEX="en" CODE="us-ascii"/>
   <LINKSIN NUM="2858"/>
  <SPEED TEXT="1308" PCT="55"/>
  <REVIEWS AVG="5.0" NUM="1"/>
  <CHILD SRATING="0"/>
   </SD>

   <KEYWORDS>
   <KEYWORD VAL="Karnataka"/>
   <KEYWORD VAL="Bangalore"/>
   </KEYWORDS><DMOZ>
   <SITE BASE="infosys.com/" TITLE="Infosys" DESC="Infosys (NASDAQ:INFY) defines, designs and delivers IT enabled business solutions. These provide you with strategic differentiation and operational superiority, thereby increasing your competitiveness. Each solution is delivered with the industry-benchmark Infosys Predictability that gives you peace of mind.">
   <CATS>
   <CAT ID="Top/Computers/Software/Consultants" TITLE="Software/Consultants" CID="379688"/>
  <CAT ID="Top/Regional/Asia/India/Karnataka/Localities/Bangalore/Business_and_Economy/Computers_and_Internet/Software" TITLE="Computers and Internet/Software" CID="497626"/>
  </CATS>
  </SITE>
  </DMOZ>
  <SD>
  <POPULARITY URL="infosys.com/" TEXT="15422"/>
  <REACH RANK="17335"/>
  <RANK DELTA="+1"/>
   </SD>
   </ALEXA>
```

i have used $xml= new SimpleXMLElement('xml data here') 
then used 
         $x=$xml->xpath('/ALEXA);
i am getting how to access LINKSIN NUM and REACH RANK here.
if i send the $x in foreach like
         foreach($x as $y){
         $y->LINKSIN NUM;
         }
it will throw the error since there is a gap between LINKSIn and NUM

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Comment: please take a look at the markup/indenting of the xml.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($dataHere);
$rank = (int)$xml->SD->REACH['RANK'];
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string

If you have an URL for the xml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($URL_to_file);
```

Comment: `$rank = (int)$xml->SD->REACH['rank'];`

Comment: `$rank = (int)$xml->SD->REACH['RANK'];`. Case matters.

Comment: $rank = (int)$xml->SD->REACH['RANK']; is not working, when i run the file, the rank cominga s zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$links = $xml->xpath('//SD/LINKSIN');
$reach = $xml->xpath('//SD/REACH');

$num  = (int)$links[0]['NUM'];
$rank = (int)$reach[0]['RANK'];
```