# how to get data from large xml file

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a large xml file which im getting from air search api now i just wanted to get data from it and show it in format like (TagName : tagdata or innerhtml)

```
<tr>
 <td> TagName :   </td>
 <td>Tag Value or its InnerHTML</td>
</tr>
```

i want to get all data into tabular form also i want whole data as while navigating i found a lot of script which does this but shows only first set of data.

link to file is http://bp.elxer.com/air_search.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: possible duplicate [A simple program to crud xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

When you get the result, its easy to make whatever you want with the data.

Comment: i have tried it but i m not satisfied can you give me a detail answer width example....

Comment: give me the static view, the way you want the html code look, I will try to implement it with xml obj properties.

Comment: sir i just want all data coming from specified file in format like below : [link](http://elxer.com/koi.png) hope you understood this time. also remaining data i want to store in array and i just want that to show them when user clicks on details or readmore

Comment: I think I gave you the solution. You want from me to do all your work for you?

Comment: it was not helpful i yet implemented by my own thanks i was asking for help though thanks you can have a glimpse at [link](http://bp.elxer.com/air_booking_admin.php)