# Extracting Elements from an RSS Feed

Tags: php, html, wordpress, rss, muse

Is it possible to extract items from an RSS feed, such as the following:
http://mudradio.wordpress.com/feed/

This is for my friend and he wants to have lots of wordpress blogs which are updated by different people all displayed on one site (which is created using Adobe Muse I think). I think he just wants the last update to be displayed on the site. Eg There may be pictures, videos (youtube) and audio (soundcloud) etc. The blog update may have lots of text and other stuff so I want it to filter the actual art content.

So the site may Look like:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|Blog 1     |Blog 2     |Blog 3     |
|Youtube Vid|Soundcloud |flickr img |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

You get the picture.

So I thought if each blog has an RSS feed, use some sort of RSS filter to just get the video, audio etc and create a new RSS feed which can be inputted in the Adobe Muse site?

What does everyone think? Any better ideas? Anyone know how the RSS filtering could be done?  I have just been attempting to use yahoo pipes but I'm not quite understanding it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+RSS+Feed+php

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Simplepie](http://Simplepie.org). Extracting data with Simplepie is piece of cake.

```
require('simplepie.inc');

$feed = new SimplePie("http://mudradio.wordpress.com/feed/");
$feed->handle_content_type();

echo $feed->get_title()."\n";

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    echo $item->get_title();
    echo $item->get_description();
}
```

And check [the demo page](http://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=http://mudradio.wordpress.com/feed/) too.

Comment: Thanks I'm checking through the docs now, So its definitely possible to display the latest post from say 10 RSS feeds?

Comment: And only display video/audio/img embeds?

Comment: @AydinHassan It'll display latest posts. If the RSS contains 10 posts it'll show 10 posts. See the [demo](http://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=http://mudradio.wordpress.com/feed/) page.

Comment: I have but thats not what I want. I want to just display an embedded youtube or soundcloud from the latest post of each RSS feed