# How to Edit XML value in cakePHP1.3?

Tags: xml, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have XML resource which provide this:

```
<container>
    <element id="first-el">
        <name>My element</name>
        <size>20</size>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>Your element</name>
        <size>30</size>
    </element>
</container>
```

What i want to do is to change value of `<size>`, where `id` is `"first-el"`, and change 20 to 50.

The resulting XML should look like this:

```
<container>
    <element id="first-el">
        <name>My element</name>
        <size>50</size>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>Your element</name>
        <size>30</size>
    </element>
 </container>
```

I tried to use `addChild()` of XML Method in CakePHP, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Comment: @Gordon: Please see may tag : xml,cakephp,and cakephp1.3, not in PHP. I want to solve it by using cakephp xml helper.

Comment: why? does it offer any substantial benefit over using a fast, easy and native extension? if you cant find one, dont use it. its waste.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what sort of additional functionality CakePHP provides in regards to XML, but there already tools for this in plain old PHP:

- [DOM Document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [Simple XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Both let you manipulate existing XML data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in CakePHP that will handle all of this for you. You can read the specifics here:

CakePHP 1.3:
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1485/Xml

CakePHP 2.0:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html