# How to edit specific value in xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Hi i have xml file with following attributes

```
<user>
 <info>
  <id>XXXXXX</id>
 </info>
</user>
```

I want to replace user id every time when the page loads and then save file with new id, the variable which gets id from user is $uid.

Comment: read `DOMDocument` ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ) or `SimpleXML` ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ) manual.

Comment: If this is all the xml within the file would it not be easier to have a template with a placeholder then you can use simple `str_replace` to insert the values then replace the file, else you would need to xpath the node and then rebuild the xml

Comment: Sorry! but as a beginner theses terms are bit advance for me it would be more easy if you can post the code here related to example above thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php)

- load the file with `$xml = simplexml_load_file('filename')`
- manipulate the value in $xml
- save the output of `$xml->asXML();`