# Another note with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

This is an example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<notes>
   <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
</notes>
```

How to add another `note` (with all its elements) using `SimpleXML`?
[addChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_addchild.asp) adds only a child to an existing tree, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first I'd get a better reference. Maybe the PHP manual, which is a great resource:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5118

This adds a node to your `notes` list:

```
<?php

$notesxml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<notes>
   <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
</notes>
XML;

$notes = new SimpleXMLElement($notesxml);

$note = $notes->addChild('note');
$note->addChild('to', 'Yourself');
$note->addChild('from', 'Billy Brown');
$note->addChild('heading', 'Another note');
$note->addChild('body', 'This is the body');

echo $notes->asXML();

?>
```

http://codepad.org/QrlU5CYm

You are looking at the right one. You just have to load the XML first, in whatever form it comes in.

Comment: Thank you, but I have an existing file, so I need to load it first, instead of creating a new one. Do you also have an example?

Comment: Wow Jared took the time to write you such a nice answer, and you just keep on pushing asking for more code? @Jared: Why not deleting the answer? And then pass me a link to one of your earlier answer I can put a bounty on?

Comment: @user1170330 - You've got three guesses which one of [these functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) is the right one, but one guess should suffice.

Comment: @hakre - Spoonfed For Life is the new Yoga position. It comes very easy for some.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yay, joga is cool.

Comment: @hakre - No no, joga is the new [Ook!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!). It's all [perfectly logical](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pretzel%20logic).