# How to add new Child to SimpleXML when one with same name already exists?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to add a child to an Simple XML object, but when an element with the same name already exists on that level it doesn't get added.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <items>
            <item></item>
        </items>
    </root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$xml->addChild('items');
print $xml->asXML();
```

I get the exact same xml as I started with, when what I really want is a second empty items element.  If I use another element name than it does get added.

Comment: In `print $xml->asXML();` what is `asXML()`;
Try this: `print_r($xml);`

Comment: Your example code works very well for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ydvjGD

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for adding a new items node in your example:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <item></item>
    </items>
</root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$xml->addChild('items', '');
var_dump($xml->asXML());
```

Which outputs:

```
string '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <item/>
    </items>
<items></items></root>
' (length=109)
```

Comment: Are you sure? Here is complete modified example. It surely works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `simpleloadxml` as alternate

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("myxml.xml");
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
$itemsNode = $sxe->items[0];
$itemsNode->addChild("item", $newValue);
$sxe->asXML("myxml.xml");
```