# PHP get xml chunk from simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml

I'm exporting some data from a kml file to mysql, there's an xml chunk `<multigeometry>` that I would like to save in the database as raw xml (because it's too complex to break down), my plan was to use json_encode and then convert the json back to xml when reading the mysql table but this task is proving to be very complicated,

Is it possible to just get the xml from the stdclass somehow? Or is there a better way of getting this saved in the database and converting back to XML?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("countries.kml")
foreach($xml->children() as $nodes){
    foreach($nodes->children() as $n => $data){
        mysql_query("insert into tbl_countries (varname,ISOA2,multigeometry) values ('".$data->name."','".substr($data->description,7,2)."','".json_encode($data->MultiGeometry)."')") or die(mysql_error());
          }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file

Comment: How was I supposed to find that? It didn't come up in related

Comment: well, there is also the easily accessible http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php and about every second question dealing with SimpleXml showing how to get the outerXml.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the xml part recreated from any SimpleXMLElement with its [asXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method.

Just replace the `json_encode($data->MultiGeometry)` part with `$data->MultiGeometry->asXML()`.

**Note:** The obligatory *please* don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated, see the [choosing mysl api page.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Thanks ya! And yeah mysql_ is discouraged which I guess means eventually it will be deprecated...