# SimpleXML getting Different Attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

How would I get a specific Attribute out of this XML feed?

Example - I have been using a line similar to this to get other XML details but I am unsure how I could change it to get a specific Attribute.

`$mainPropertyDetails = $mainPropertyUrl->Attributes->attribute;`

**Attributes:**

```
<Attributes>
<Attribute>
<Name>bedrooms</Name>
<DisplayName>Bedrooms</DisplayName>
<Value>4 bedrooms</Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
<Name>bathrooms</Name>
<DisplayName>Bathrooms</DisplayName>
<Value>2 bathrooms</Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
<Name>property_type</Name>
<DisplayName>Property type</DisplayName>
<Value>House</Value>
</Attribute>
```

Comment: Use `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); var_dump($sxe->Attribute[0]);` Where `0` is the specific ID of the attribute you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleXML` implements these nodes as an array. If you were to `var_dump()` this, you would see something like:

```
// Dump the whole Attributes array
php > var_dump($xml->Attributes);

object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
  ["Attribute"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(8) "bedrooms"
      ["DisplayName"]=>
      string(8) "Bedrooms"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(10) "4 bedrooms"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(9) "bathrooms"
      ["DisplayName"]=>
      string(9) "Bathrooms"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(11) "2 bathrooms"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (3) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(13) "property_type"
      ["DisplayName"]=>
      string(13) "Property type"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(5) "House"
    }
  }
}
```

It is therefore just a matter of accessing specific ones by their array index:

```
// Get the second Attribute node
var_dump($xml->Attributes[0]->Attribute[1]);

object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
  ["Name"]=>
  string(9) "bathrooms"
  ["DisplayName"]=>
  string(9) "Bathrooms"
  ["Value"]=>
  string(11) "2 bathrooms"
}
```

#### Get the Attribute node based on a child's value:

Using [`xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) you can query for the parent `Attribute` node based on a child's text value:

```
// Get the Attribute containing the Bathrooms DisplayName
// Child's text value is queried via [AttrName/text()="value"]
var_dump($xml->xpath('//Attributes/Attribute[DisplayName/text()="Bathrooms"]');

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "bathrooms"
    ["DisplayName"]=>
    string(9) "Bathrooms"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(11) "2 bathrooms"
  }
}
```