# How to delete a node in XML

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Why is my code not functioning to delete an element located in my asset.xml

Here is my xml code inside a php file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["delete"])) {
        $node = $_GET["node"]; //get from form
        $xmldoc->load('asset.xml');
        $y= $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName("asset")[$node];
        $xmldoc.documentElement.removeChild($y);}
?>
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assets>
  <asset>
    <AssetType>PROJECTOR</AssetType>
    <Product>DELL</Product>
    <Brand>DELL</Brand>
  </asset>
</Assets>
```

Comment: `$xmldoc.documentElement.removeChild($y);` - What's that?! Please do us all a favour and *paste* code, not type from memory.

Comment: i already paste it.. the code suppose to become like what?

Comment: If this is your code, PHP would give you very obvious signs that something is wrong; have you tried to run the code? What are the errors that you see?

Comment: i'm using the Uniform Server as my local server. There are no error displayed. However, each time I click the button (name = 'delete'), the page become a totally blank page

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to save the file for the changes to persist

```
$xmldoc->save('asset.xml');
```

---

Seeing as the code you posted is actual code

[`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) you'll have to access the elements via [`DOMNodelist::item`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)

```
$y = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName("asset")->item($node);//assuming $node is an integer < # of matched nodes
```

`->` is used to access object properties in php not [`.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) so `$xmldoc.documentElement.removeChild($y);` should be

```
$xmldoc->documentElement->removeChild($y);
```

or better yet

```
$y->parentNode->removeChild($y);
```

Comment: I already did the update,
the result is, I got a totally blank page.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first save file  try

```
$xmldoc->save('asset.xml');
```

and

The `removeChild()` method removes a specified node.
The `removeAttribute()` method removes a specified attribute.

Comment: i want to remove the <asset></asset>, there are a few <asset></asset> inside the xml file.