# Php form to add xml data to xml file

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

I am trying to create a form that will allow me to add new records in an xml file using php and xml dom. The xml file is on the server and i want the client to be able to type in and add to the xml file.
Heres my code so far

```
$data = "books.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);
$book = $xml->addChild("book");
$author = $_POST["author"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$publisher = $_POST["publisher"];
$book->addChild("author", $author);
$book->addChild("title", $title);
$book->addChild("publisher", $publisher);

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

The form

```
<form action="addchild.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="author" />
Email: <input type="text" name="title" />
Comment: <input type="text" name="publisher" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The XML

```
<books>
<book>
<author>Jack Herrington</author>
<title>PHP Hacks</title>
<publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
<book>
<author>Jack Herrington</author>
<title>Podcasting Hacks</title>
<publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
</book>
</books>
```

Comment: So what ? What do you what/need?

Comment: try `$book->appendChild("author", $author);`

Comment: Your knowing about DOM, about Webforms, about PHP. What is it that you are missing? :)

Comment: its not working the xml dosent update