# How to read in XML strings as variables?

Tags: php, xml, string

Try this query:

http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/gobabola?key=135a6187-af83-4e85-85c1-1a28db11d5da

How do I simply read in the suggestions as variables? I can't seem to find anything that explains this.

Comment: By using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). [Here is a good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Comment: And there are [several examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+xml+with+php) which cover the process of loading the file via `simplexml_load_file()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleXmlIterator. That's really easy to use and you will be able to perform a foreach on the object you will get.

[Library source](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php)

For example with file_get_contents or replace with curl if you prefer:

```
    $feed = new SimpleXmlIterator(file_get_contents('http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/gobabola?key=135a6187-af83-4e85-85c1-1a28db11d5da'));
    foreach ($feed->suggestion as $suggestion) {
        echo $value;
      }
```