# How to save xml error message in log file?

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

When I access xml, there is error message like this :

```
<ErrorMSG>Credit limit exceed. Booking cannot be proceed. </ErrorMSG></Response>
```

I want save the error message in log file

How to save xml error message in log file?

Thank you

Comment: What language, what platform?

Comment: @Tim, My language is PHP. My platform is Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) if you want something super quick:

```
file_put_contents('<path to log file>', $stringInput, FILE_APPEND);
```

Where "path to log file" is the path + name of the file you want to write to, and $stringInput is the string representation of the error. FILE_APPEND is a flag so that every time you call file_put_contents(), a new line gets added to the file rather than rewriting the file.

As an alternative, check out [log5php](https://github.com/teamlazerbeez/PHP/tree/master/Log5PHP) which gives more control.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My case is like this. My code is like this : http://pastebin.com/vGSqiRbA. When I click button submit, I can access xml. But the xml display error message. How to save xml error message in log file? I still difficult to implement your answer.

Comment: @mosestoh What does your PHP script look like? It should be whatever script is mapped to endpoint that's currently set as action="http://xxxxxxxxxxx" in the HTML you've pasted. Knowing what your PHP script looks like will let me understand what's going on.

Comment: It is a API url. I take the data from the url(Request) to get a response XML