# How to Update config file in codeigniter and save config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way that we can update the value of config file and save these values into config file.

For example, I have:

```
   $config['base_url']  = 'http://localhost.com';
   $config['test'] = '';
```

I want to change the value of $config['test']
      $this->config->set_item('test','something');
 and save this value into config file. so, my config file should be

```
  $config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost.com';
  $config['test'] = 'something';
```

Thanks.

Comment: **$this->config->set_item('test','something');** will itself set the value of 'test' to 'something' at run-time. You don't need to **save** it again.

Comment: at run-time, it is OK. but if I want to save the file. Is it possible?

Comment: You can but I am wondering why you want to do that.

Comment: for example, I have a blog name which the default value "My Blog". then if the administrator change this blog name to "Something else", so that I need to save the file.

Comment: So if there is only one blog and assuming administrator which can change the blog name also has the access to config.php file, he can simply manually edit the blog name in the config.php file?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237291/reading-and-writing-configuration-files and http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Why not use a database for this functionality?

Comment: that's Ok. I will use db

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using a hook that pulls this data from your database (as suggested by cchana).  This way you can easily update it without compromising security of your config file.