# How to create a global configuration file in php

Tags: php, function, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading and Writing Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237291/reading-and-writing-configuration-files)

Most of my functions depends on settings.

As of now I'm storing my setting values in database.

For example to display ad in a page i'm checking my database whether to display ad or not

I mean like this

```
$display_ad = 'get value from database';

if ($display_ad) {
echo 'Ad code goes here';
}
```

This is fine. But the fact is I have more than 100 settings. So I think my databse load will be reduced if I define the value in a settings.php file like

```
define('DISPLAY_AD', true); 

if (DISPLAY_AD) {
echo 'Ad code goes here';
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the right way. Is `define()` is the correct solution. Or is there any better and faster solution available?

Comment: Using define makes your code untestable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define()` is quite a good way of doing things. An alternative is to define a global array. such as

```
$config['display_ad']=true;
$config['something_else']='a value';
//...
function doSomething() {
   global $config;
   if ($config['display_ad']) echo 'Ad code goes here';
}
```

The latter way is what many projects use, such as phpmyadmin, the reason could be, that you cannot `define()` a non-scalar value, e.g. `define('SOME_ARRAY',array('a','b'))` is invalid.

Comment: I've always operated on the premise that if `global` is the answer, you're asking the wrong question, and need to re-evaluate the problem. +1 for getting OP where he needs to go, -1 for `global`.

Comment: @Bracketworks I personally use `define()` wherever possible, but I accept, that a **global** configuration might be one of the questions, that can rightfully be answered by a `global` statement.

Comment: @EugenRieck I object. Rarely is configuration truly `global`, and as an application grows different modules (*or whatever*) will require independent configuration management. Starting global and working backwards to local (*especially in a growing code-base*) is a task I wouldn't give my enemies.

Answer (score 1):

Several options, like those mentioned, include `.ini` files (*using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), etc.*), XML (*some concoction with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) perhaps*) but I prefer keeping config in native PHP.

The `include()` construct allows for one to `return` from the included file. This allows you to:

**config.php**

```
return [
    'foo' => [
        'bar' => [
            'qux' => true,
        ],
        'zip' => false,
    ],
];
```

**elsewhere.php**

```
function loadConfig($file) {
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
    return (array) call_user_func(function() use($file) {
        // I always re-scope for such inclusions, however PHP 5.4 introduced 
        // $this rebinding on closures so it's up to you
        return include($file);
    });
}

$config = loadConfig('config.php');

if ($config['foo']['bar']['qux']) {
    // yeop
}
if ($config['foo']['zip']) {
    // nope
}
```

Special care needs to be taken, as when you try to dereference a non-existent dimension, PHP will poop on you:

```
if ($config['i']['am']['not']['here']) { // poop

}
```

Creating a wrapper class/functions to manage configuration to your needs is reasonably trivial though. You can add support for cascading configuration (*a la `web.config` in the ASP world*), caching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to execute would be an ini file.  You create a file that looks like this:

```
value1 = foo
value2 = bar
value3 = baz
```

Then, from PHP, you can execute this:

```
$iniList = get_ini_file("/path/to/ini/file/you/just/made");
if ($iniList['value1'] == 'foo') {
    print "This will print because the value was set from get_ini_file."
}
```

If you have a lot of similar constants, that's better than dozens of define methods and quicker than database fetches.

Comment: I think you meant `parse_ini_file()`

Answer (score 0):

you can allso make a class like here:
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#92085)